# Not satisfied with the reason given to close my question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

After some initial comments I edited [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609921/ambigous-treatment-of-application). It is more clear and Jon Skeet agreed with me.

Even though I feel that the question is quite clear, I am ready to provide more specific information or edits if required. However, my question was closed as "Not a real question". Why did that happen and how can I improve my question to have it reopened?

Comment: Jon Skeet agrees the question is _clearer_, as in not completely misleading any more. It still lacks code, details about exactly what is not working.

Comment: +1 Ain't it the truth!

Answer (score 11):

Why your question was most likely closed:

- It is *very* hard to follow.
- It smells as being too localized.
- We've no idea in what state your project is, you're only mentioning "using UserControls" but it sounds like those are provided via another project or a dll...it is hard to take a guess without knowing the exact structure if your project.
- You say you fixed a problem by switching an option in the IDE which seems to confirm the assumption that you have a very interesting project structure.
- Also you say "...none of method/properties/event are fired as I coded." Which yields a big "What?!" the first time, and the second time the question "So nothing works in your program?". But it sounds more like you're unable to debug the project because the debugger is unable to step into it *or* does not find appropriate debugging symbols for it.
- Another possibility is that not your project is the problem, but you've managed to mess up your development environment...which might be hard or impossible to take a guess about.

Lot's of guess work there...so it got closed.

Comment: Is there need to teach teacher?. UserControl mention there that means it's obviously came from the .dll application. or do you have any other application for create UserControl except .dll application. Here I am Student and you all are my respected teacher.

Comment: ... For a Software Engineer each application is interesting. It's not important whether it is big or small. If you don't respect your own application than forget to received respect from others.

Comment: I will be back soon. This is my pray time. Sorry for interruption.

Comment: UserControls are just Objects like every other, they can be in the same project, a referenced project, a referenced dll or even being directly injected via Reflection...I also don't get the rest of your comment.

Comment: The Usercontrol coment is related to your answer at third dot. where you take a guess about UserControl.

Comment: This is regarding to your fifth dot answer. I have already mention in my question below comment that the application is executed by without error after fixed the problem but all the data reference which I have coded in my method, event, properties are not display as it is displayed in starting before the problem execution.

Comment: ... due to execution of application successfully I am not able to debug it. How can I debug it without application force to debug it via exception.

Comment: ... and this about your sixth dot answer. I have provided link for example in my comment to the question below.And suppose it is mess up environment by me than there must be a way to re get it.