# Not Satisfied with [Close] how to reopen that or what should i do?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

Yesterday I have asked one question in SO about android and I got one answer. I had chat with that developer and he helped me to find out solution but bad luck.

When I open my SO account and check my Question status it was closed. I know question should be only close when that is improper or not having code or logcat or may be out side or Programming.

Where in my question i had put my RnD work , my File & my logcat also even i have set my question title with real mean.There are no single thing that should be found to `[CLOSE]` my question.

[Here is my Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015033/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed) & [I found something related in Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157084/not-satisfied-with-the-reason-given-to-close-my-question)

My Text and code Formatting is also okay as per SO rule.

How can I reopen my question or what should I do ?

Comment: Question looks good, you can reopen it by clicking on reopen button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question looks like a valid question. You can re-open it in two way,

- Either requesting users with 3K reputation
- Flag your question with "other" option, mention to the moderator that "I have edited the question can you please re-open it ?

Comment: He is having 250+ reputation so he can cast reopen vote on his own post. And whenever any closed question is edited, it comes into the reopen review queue automatically.

Comment: now i need just 3 more votes for reopen. if you guys can vote for me then it would be good for me

Comment: @chintankhetiya, i am the first one to vote for re-open :) & him056 is 2nd one. lets wait for 3 more users.